# Canvas auto resize height

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas that i'm using to print a thermal receipt. It works great when defining the width and height with exact pixels and the content fits within the defined height.

The problem comes when there is too much content for the defined height. **The canvas doesn't adjust its height to the content and so everything below the defined height is cut off.**

**How do i adjust to the height of the content?**

First time using canvas so any suggestions are welcome.

Please let me know if any sample code is required here as i'm not sure what would be relevant?

Cheers

Comment: this question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211920/make-canvas-height-auto

Comment: not sure that this answers my question because i'm looking for a solution to resize according to the content height not the height of the view port window. cheers

Comment: Apologies, and my bad James, I "skimmed" the suggested dup-link but I see now with more awake eyes that it isn't what you needed. I could vote for reopen but I see you opened a new question so I'll leave it as-is.